# Access a publisher created at the top of a Combine chain further down the chain

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to create a function that will return me a struct constructed from two publishers within a chain of Combine calls,  something like this pseudocode

```
struct UpdatedPilotsInfo {
    let pilots: [JSON]
    let squad: JSON
}

func buildInfoIdeal() {
        func processPilots(squad: JSON) -> AnyPublisher<[JSON] , XWSImportError> { ... }
        func loadSquad() -> AnyPublisher<JSON, XWSImportError> { ... }
        
        let squadInfoPublisher: AnyPublisher<(JSON, [JSON]), XWSImportError> = JSONSection
            .SquadService_XWSImport_New
            .SquadService
            .loadSquad() // AnyPublisher<JSON, XWSImportError>
            .flatMap(processPilots) // AnyPublisher<[JSON], XWSImportError>
            .???    // AnyPublisher<(JSON, [JSON]), XWSImportError>
            .map{ tuple -> UpdatedPilotsInfo in
                return UpdatedPilotsInfo(squad: tuple.0, pilots: tuple.1)
            }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

My issue is that I don’t know how I can make an upstream publisher created at the top of the chain (`loadSquad`) available further down the chain.  In the example above, I pass the output of the `loadSquad()` to `processPilots()` and I’d like to build a `UpdatedPilotsInfo` from the results of `loadSquad()` and `processPilots()`.  I think that I can accomplish this by doing the following, but I’d like to have a simple chain instead of all this code:

```
    func buildInfo() -> AnPublisher<UpdatedPilotsInfo, XWSImportError> {
        func processPilots(squad: JSON) -> AnyPublisher<[JSON] , XWSImportError> { ... }
        func loadSquad() -> AnyPublisher<JSON, XWSImportError> { ... }
        
        let squadPublisher: AnyPublisher<JSON, XWSImportError> = JSONSection
            .SquadService_XWSImport_New
            .SquadService
            .loadSquad() // AnyPublisher<JSON, XWSImportError>
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        let updatedPilots: AnyPublisher<[JSON], XWSImportError> = squadPublisher
            .flatMap{ [weak self] squad -> AnyPublisher<[JSON], XWSImportError in
                let s = self
                return s.processPilots(squad)
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        let zip = Publishers.Zip(squadPublisher, updatedPilots)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()  // AnyPublisher<(JSON, [JSON]), XWSImportError>

        return zip.map{ tuple -> UpdatedPilotsInfo in 
            return UpdatedPilotsInfo(squad: tuple.0, pilots: tuple.1)
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher() 
    }
```

Is this something I can accomplish with an existing operator or do I need to create a custom operator?

Comment: Downvoted for not being a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `.flatMap { Just($0) }` is exactly the same as `.map { $0 }`. And both are a no-op.

This means you can pass down the parameter using just while combining it with some other publisher that does some actual work.

```
loadSquad
    .flatMap { Publishers.Zip(Just($0).setFailureType(to: Error.self), processPilots($0)) }
    .map { UpdatedPilotsInfo(squad: $0.0, pilots: $0.1) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

So with the above, we are passing the response from `loadSquad` along with the response from `processPilots` inside the `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understand, you have two publishers and you want to combine them, so that when both publishers receive their outputs a structure is created. Right?

I tried to create an example in Playground that is very similar to your problem.

```
typealias JSON = Int
typealias XWSImportError = Error

// Just for simulation.
func processPilots() -> AnyPublisher<[JSON] , XWSImportError> {
    Just<[JSON]>([1, 2, 3]).setFailureType(to: XWSImportError.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func loadSquad() -> AnyPublisher<JSON, XWSImportError> {
    Just<JSON>(4).setFailureType(to: XWSImportError.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

struct UpdatedPilotsInfo {
    let pilots: [JSON]
    let squad: JSON
}

// Simpler solution
func buildInfoIdeal() -> AnyPublisher<UpdatedPilotsInfo, XWSImportError> {
    processPilots()
        .zip(loadSquad())
        .map { UpdatedPilotsInfo(pilots: $0.0, squad: $0.1) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// Test
let subscription = buildInfoIdeal()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // Handle a completion.
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    })

// Calling order doesn't matter.
// The result is always the same: UpdatedPilotsInfo(pilots: [1, 2, 3], squad: 4)
processPilots()
loadSquad()
```

Hopefully I could help you.

Comment: The `processPilots(squad:)` needs to take as input the output of `loadSquad()`